# Can anybody tell me how to fix this error - if it's possible

Tags: error

Error: Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool. I understand the call function is better used than transfer.

How can I explicitly fix this error and use the call function??

function bookProperty(
uint256 propertyId,
uint256 startDate,
uint256 endDate
) public payable {
uint256 numberOfDays = (endDate - startDate) / 1 days; // 86400000

```
    require(
        msg.value > numberOfDays = properties[propertyId].pricePerDay,
        "Send more Eth"
    );

    (bool sent, ) = payable(properties[propertyId].owner).call{value: msg.value}("");
    require(sent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison seems incorrect. Instead of the assignment operator, you need to multiply.

```
require(
    msg.value > numberOfDays * properties[propertyId].pricePerDay,
    "Send more Eth"
);
```